# How to prove this this integral equality which contain nonlocal operator, $(-\partial_{xx})^{1/2}$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, singular-integral-equations

Suppose that $\theta(t,x)$ is even about $x$ and is smooth. $0\le \gamma<1/2$, $0<\delta<1-2\gamma$. $\Lambda=(-\partial_{xx})^{1/2}$

**My Question:** How to prove that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta}}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\theta(t,x)-\theta(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta+\gamma}}dx
$$
**My efforts:**
Since $\theta$ is even, $\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta$ is even. Using parseval's theorem, we can obtain
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{|x|^{1+\delta}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}( \theta(t,x)-\theta(t,0))\Lambda^{\gamma}(|x|^{-(1+\delta)})dx
$$
However, $\Lambda^{\gamma}(|x|^{-(1+\delta)})$ have nonsense.

This question is from the last proof of this paper. Thanks for any help!
[Blow-up of solutions for a 1D transport equation with nonlocal velocity and supercritical dissipation](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272585/1-s2.0-S0001870808X00040/1-s2.0-S0001870807003076/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIBxITU7zdzlOx6HXWtys7A%2BPs5lqnXW%2FRziEL5CvuusYAiB7UlHsaQDX%2F9MsxEyGPcNUF%2Fh%2FRo5%2FIgsUcxsfaijBCCqDBAi9%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMmmZ7CCd3zpnxCmifKtcD7iKzznthikH9JUevrXWtgGF7qK4wQca4FS0nYPvzpjXhJPtNDceuLP8STMZriv7udhKuw5fhJ1o6U3Jfr73M41y48XzLNHGaAzJ8OeE3XJ7u0zYQvxfCnuwfPTzz8%2FkGApDoCC%2FKGSSjq%2BmrUmAZdfA6DxDFSEptFI%2FAm%2F%2Fm8mgALtakR%2BlP5JLceH3x3Ug9xmQtz21dzXeNXIy%2FHDpHvPKiZPoJl%2Bqgy1PFFVXrIEW907LRHolCfNOiOm3OzYkKweMz3qleXrxpLCckoardNu90PqUiAwm4%2BeKceNML1CGlrx%2FkanQRQIZeh%2BAyK3en5zu7o05Xb1aZ3zJpCy1V48ARuKsVr0Vnm%2BbtuWoHiQZ0YWiDXxnKa1IhUUycquofo7l0dsHP0pfBRTm5HpCgIWRuVG06HMMYNa77%2Bu0oZKs9jSi5m%2FhAoo4nqz5OXPdtBTSdisBh3nYNenlN07xPsQKmsYiztKGrS8JHWcmYhRVTeP1%2Baa9Gf1VN1mzW%2B1IoS6fLfADjmBbjvbQFPKgY6yNXHQK1CUxE27KxfOQMmexLW7L80LVcmD2S0n5fzGe%2FubjFLCK8L3cXUDmskJPdPM2F886qlH6PCvkAHLJqOnE%2BIel5ydB3MNO3q4cGOqYBZQjnGZR6qdA8n%2Bl29mW4xfnazLassGSq1lh%2FbMvuC2NXyspNSUt8Y8M8OrN%2F1mbsaVMV8EcTJ9lKeQ0gFsW86ZnzgfvB2%2FN4tnRv4s76uLd%2BsTuZWWULFhXbGreGyItdw%2BR9Gsc4A73oRr2vHi0l%2BSQ8oPpH7NdCx4X0JLn8W82k6S%2F4j0Dtz8akNUuVbXaaZg6396K5BW3q7dH8ID%2Fr3PPTLgik0g%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210711T133725Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZFP56MEU%2F20210711%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7b3cb945bbaec7e62bd4ab47e4ddcdb7c5d39bc1a3f79c168a3cf0f9369ad291&hash=37a2dba19e6a243b3bc7df9fee65282acbbeb87293841407deed49ad1ad0bbf7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0001870807003076&tid=spdf-791c0c2e-cbf4-4de1-85f8-cb680a7b9e29&sid=bbd7a41b73a2514507680db2d7ed01d5c5c1gxrqa&type=client)

Comment: It looks like this is a simple reformulation of the identity $(-\partial_{xx})^{\delta/2} (-\partial_{xx})^{\gamma/2} f(0) = (-\partial_{xx})^{(\delta+\gamma)/2} f(0)$, where $f(x) = \theta(t,x)$, but an appropriate constant is missing in the right-hand side. (Note: nothing seems to depend on $t$ here.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I get an answer in MSE. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195771/how-to-prove-this-integral-equality-which-contains-the-nonlocal-operator-pa/4195979#4195979